# Blurry Loading setInterval

Tags: javascript, function, variables, setinterval, loading

Im working on 50 day 50 js projects. https://github.com/bradtraversy/50projects50days/tree/master/blurry-loading

Regarding the blurry loading. I wonder why the setInterval works when the brower loads the page, without calling the function? How the int variable and setInterval worked?

Thank you in advance - jsnoob

````
const int = setInterval(myCallback, 20);

function myCallback() {
  load++;
  if (load > 99) {
    clearInterval(int);
  }}```
````

Comment: Are you asking why the interval starts?

Comment: Simply, Yes!           Yes! Yes!    .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interval starts on the line when you declare your `int` constant.
**In fact** this line

```
const int = setInterval(myCallback, 20);
```

Is exactly the same as this line

```
setInterval(myCallback, 20);
```

Except that the former saves the id number, say `3`, of the interval so that you can stop it later.

**To declare a function that starts an interval when called**, do it like this:

```
const int = ()=>{setInterval(myCallback, 20);}
// The following line will not start the interval immediately.
// You can later call int() to start the interval.
int();
// NOTE: this will not save a reference to the interval's id number.
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You completely gave the perfect answer. I'm no longer confused by knowing that 'id' belongs to that interval and was designed to stop it some time later. :)